How do I control the appearance of borders (and labels) while recording video in Google Earth Pro?
For a client I'm creating an animation in Google Earth Pro (i.e. the desktop software).
To make the following more comprehensible: Google Earth Pro, like Google Maps, allows you to save tours (referred to as 'recording'), which essentially are sequences of locations you can fly through. GEP additionally allows you to use its built-in Movie Maker to record videos of these tours. I'll refer to the first as 'tour', and to the second as 'video'.
The Issue
I create a tour, and can turn labels/borders/&c. on and off under Layers as it is recording ('on-the-fly' is an appropriate term). After saving this tour, I can see the switching-on and -off of these features back in the video.
However, there are a few issues with this. In the video:

The features don't consistently turn on or off (e.g. sometimes a recorded video won't show any labels or borders, even though they are activated under Layers, and work in former or subsequent recorded videos);
Drawn features, like borders, seemingly randomly appear at lower definition (see images below—I think most people familiar with Google Earth/Maps will recognize this), even after making sure I flew the tour to make GEP cache this data (if at all it works that way).

I couldn't find a way to control these things. I tried increasing the Memory Cache, which didn't have any effect.
Is there any way to get a more predictable result when it comes to the appearance of features while recording videos in Google Earth Pro?

Comparison of different quality in drawing of borders:









Crude borders
Much higher-definition borders (note the additional labels)



